# Copying data from two files and feeding it into a comparison sheet

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have two documents titled Old Cal and New Cal. I want to be able to take the tables from each separate file and copy them into a new comparison file automatically. The only issue is, there will continuously be new documents that need to be inputted into a new comparison sheet every time the data is collected. For example, this time the files are called Old Cal and New Cal, but then after those comparisons I will have two brand new files named Blue and Red with completely new information that I will need to compare on another new page. I need help writing a macro that can automatically populate the comparison sheet I need to make between the two documents every time even though there will be different files every time. Let me know if more info is needed, any help is welcome. THANKS!

Comment: You can use `Application.GetOpenFilename()` to ask your user to select one or more files.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Williams says using `Application.GetOpenFilename()` is a great solution.  It will open the standard excel open file dialog, but will not actually open the file, it just gives you the file name.

To actually open the workbook you can use `Application.Workbooks.Open()`.  Here is a snippet of code that you can modify for your use.

```
Dim file1 as String
Dim file2 as String
Dim book1 as Workbook
Dim book2 as Workbook
Dim comp as Workbook
Dim targetSheet as Worksheet
Dim copySheet as Worksheet
Dim lastRow as Long
Dim lastCol as Long

Set comp = Application.ActiveWorkbook

file1 = Application.getOpenFilename
file2 = Application.getOpenFilename

If file1 <> "False" AND file2 <> "False" Then
   Set book1 = Application.Workbooks.Open(file1)
   Set book2 = Application.Workbooks.Open(file2)

   'Copy the contents from the first sheet of each of the files to a new sheet in a new sheet
   comp.Worksheets.add After:=comp.Worksheets(comp.Worksheets.count)
   Set targetSheet = comp.Worksheets(comp.Worksheets.count)
   Set copySheet = book1.Worksheets(1)
   lastRow = copySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
   lastCol = copySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
   copySheet.Range(copySheet.Cells(1, 1), copySheet.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy
   targetSheet.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial

   Set copySheet = book2.Worksheets(1)
   lastRow = copySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
   lastCol = copySheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column
   copySheet.Range(copySheet.Cells(1, 1), copySheet.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Copy
   lastRow = targetSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
   targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1).PasteSpecial

   book1.Close
   book2.Close
End If
```

This probably won't solve you're problem exactly, but it should be a good starting point.  Right now it will copy the first sheet of both workbooks (one ontop of the other) onto a new sheet in the original workbook.

Hope this helps, and welcome to SO